# How to create a gravel pile using geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, particles, geometry

How can i create a pile of spheres using geometry nodes?
i want to later add fluid simulation to go in between the gaps
but as in natures the spheres touches each other and not overlap

Comment: please improve/edit your question, so that it is clear what you want - as you wrote in the comment. Thanks.

Comment: Look into distributing with regular [sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing)    Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106243/how-to-animate-spirals-on-packed-spheres-using-animation-nodes

Comment: This is helpful thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. add cube
2. add UV Sphere
3. add geometry nodes to cube
4. scale down uv Sphere in edit mode
5. use this node tree

[image]

5. play a little bit with distance so that the spheres don't touch each other

result:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

1. add a cube, delete top face and add solidify modifier, rigid body, passive
2. add a uvSphere, give it a rigid body, shape: Sphere, Sensitivity: collision margin: 0
3. copy that sphere as often as you need it and move it so it doesn't intersect with the others
4. run the animation until you are satisfied, then select all spheres and press object->apply-> visual transform
5. now you can delete all rigid bodies and do whatever you want to do with it

[image]

result:

[image]

video tutorial:

https://youtu.be/bQdIfseupK4

Comment: did that. the thing is its not a pile that each instance "knows" not to overlap with another instance and that they are all ontop of each other as close as possible like real world pile

Comment: Then - in my opinion - geometry nodes is the wrong tool. You should use physics.

Comment: Hey Thanks Chris. But, I need to do this for a huge pile - meaning 3000 objects. Rigid body is too demanding for this job.

Comment: No it’s not. I just tried it out. Maybe you should first try it out than just write what you are thinking. And here is the proof: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5JgS.png. But of course...you can search for another method, but i think there no alternative for that if you want a "realistic" pile look. But why should i argue with people who are even too lazy to improve their question and too lazy to test things out!?